# No in browser video playback and/or sound W10 1809 Bootcamp MBA2018

Tags: bootcamp

Upon release I installed W10 1809 on a 2018 MacBook Air (i.e. the most recent one).

Bootcamp audio drivers are v 6.1.7200 (most recent) and macOS Mojave was and is fully up to date.

Even so, video playback is broken and there is no sound, nor does the mic pick up any sound.

In macOS everything works perfectly.

Initially I thought it was something specific to the new device/new W10 version but so many months after release of both, I'm starting to wonder...

Did anyone here encounter this?

There are scattered reports online but no solutions:

https://discussions.apple.com/thread/250209569

Comment: Does video playback work otherwise?  In other words, can you play a video file outside your browser?

Comment: what browser ??

Comment: Any browser on the platform. Chrome, Safari, FF... No video playback elsewhere either. Again, on macOS, everything works so the speakers/mic ar not physically broken. Truly bizarre...